# Accessing windows performance counters using PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, windows

I was wondering if it is possible to access windows performance counters using php?

Basically, I already have a PHP application, and I have a basic vb script that accesses the performance counters and creates variables from them. What I need is to be able to access these same performance counters using PHP and therefore set them as variables within my PHP application.

If that isn't possible, is there a way I can use the vb script within the PHP application to use the variables? I would rather not do it this way as I have limited knowledge in that sense, but if that is the only way I will have to learn.

I can post the code if and when required, however for now I just need to know if what I'm asking is possible.

Thanks

EDIT:

My vb code is as follows:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim perfActiveUsers As New PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727", "Sessions Active", "__Total__")
    Dim perfAlcInstances As New PerformanceCounter("Alchemy Web Pool Manager", "Alchemy Instances Active")
    Dim perfAlcAvgResponse As New PerformanceCounter("Alchemy Web Pool Manager", "Request Average Response Time")
    Dim perfAlcQueue As New PerformanceCounter("Alchemy Web Pool Manager", "Requests Queued")
    Dim perfAlcTimeout As New PerformanceCounter("Alchemy Web Pool Manager", "Requests Timed Out")
    Dim perfAlcTotal As New PerformanceCounter("Alchemy Web Pool Manager", "Requests Total")
    Dim totalDBs As String = "0"
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim ConnString As String = "Server=ALCHEMYSVR\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AuServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=STORETECSERVICE\administrator;Password=westend"
    Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection() 'The SQL Connection
    Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand() 'The SQL Command
    Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader   'The Local Data Store



    SQLStr = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AusDatabase"
    SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString 'Set the Connection String
    SQLConn.Open() 'Open the connection

    SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
    SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr 'Sets the SQL String
    SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader 'Gets Data



    Do
        While (SQLdr.Read()) 'While Data is Present 
            totalDBs = SQLdr(0)
            MsgBox(SQLdr(0)) 'Show data in a Message Box
        End While
    Loop While SQLdr.NextResult() 'Move to the Next Record
    SQLdr.Close() 'Close the SQLDataReader
    SQLConn.Close() 'Close the connection



    'Display The Values
    lblAlcInstances.Text = perfAlcInstances.NextValue()
    lblActiveUsers.Text = perfActiveUsers.NextValue()
    Label1.Text = perfAlcAvgResponse.NextValue()
    Label2.Text = perfAlcQueue.NextValue()
    Label3.Text = perfAlcTimeout.NextValue()
    Label4.Text = perfAlcTotal.NextValue()
    Label5.Text = totalDBs

End Sub

End Class
```

It is the performance counter values that are assigned to the labels at the bottom that I require passing to php as a variable. I have tried the PHP exec but cant grasp how I pass the variables in the vb script to variables in PHP.

Comment: You can call your vbscript with phps exec();

Comment: And would that then allow me to use the variables that are defined within the vb script?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter to exec is a return variable that will hold the value returned from the vbs

Comment: How would I then define those variables as variables within my PHP script? Sorry, I'm relatively inexperienced

Comment: Thats .net not vbscript. If you are using .net, create a console application and have it output the data you want to the screen (console.writeline(data);). Have the data in a string format that can easily be read by php, eg json/xml

Comment: echo $data = shell_exec('cmd'); var_dump(json_decode($data));

Comment: Hi I tried the above example and it just outputs the word NULL on the screen

Answer (score 0):

It can get a little nasty if you try to fetch windows system data via PHP.

If you already have a VB script, you have two common options:

1. use exec and parse the data from your script. i would NOT recommend that.
2. add a little more code to your VB script: it should run periodically and write the current data into a database/key-value-storage/textfile from where you can retrieve the data via php

Comment: I think I may be able to manage the second option with a bit of research. Can I ask why you wouldn't recommend the first option?

Comment: Also the data is live and therefore needs to be up-to-date. I imagine this wouldn't be possible with the second option, is this correct?

Comment: I know you said it can get a little nasty fetching the windows system data via php, but is it still possible for what I need? I have tried all other suggestions and googled it but cant get it working!